# SQL Server 2005 Express - Activty Monitor - Show details is empty, how can I tell what the SQL statement that started the process is?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Trying to fix a problem on our server - a very expensive query is using a lot of our CPU.

When I use activity monitor, sometimes you can use the show details for the process, and it will show you the sql that is running the query. Not always though.

I can see the process now, but how can I tell what query text is responsible? I can identify the source if I have the sql, but at the moment I have nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following query.

```
SELECT TOP 20
    qs.sql_handle,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_worker_time AS Total_CPU,
    total_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        qs.total_worker_time/1000000,
    average_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        (qs.total_worker_time/1000000) / qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_elapsed_time,
    total_elapsed_time_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000,
   st.text,
   qp.query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
    CROSS apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) AS qp
ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC
```

Then may I suggest that you get yourself a copy of the awesome [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/12/03/who-is-active-v9-57-fast-comprehensive-dmv-collection.aspx) stored procedure written and shared for free courtesy of Adam Machanic. You can use the procedure to identify all currently running queries, including a wealth of associated information such as the amount of CPU used, IO, the execution plan, query text, blocking etc.

Comment: Thanks, the link to the adam mechanic query was useful. I did however find a more concise way of getting the info i was after: DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<Process ID>) !

Comment: @BomdDefused: Absolutely, that's an excellent method to use provided you already know which SPID you are looking for.